# SQL Get Count Across 3 Tables

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have a 3 tables, one with these two columns

```
table1:

id, name
0   foo
1   etc
2   example

table2:
id  table1_id
0       1
1       0
2       2

table3:
id  table2_id
 0     1
 1     0
 2     0
```

Which query can I find all 'name's from table1 where ALL ids in table2 have a count of atleast n in table3? i.e if n was 1 it should return foo and etc

EDIT:

Explained poorly, I'm trying to get the name of every record in table1 where ALL corresponding records in table2 (i.e records where the column table1_ID is equal to each id within table1. In my example tables, each ID has one) have a count in table3 of atleast n.

If n was 1, as the table2_id 0 appears twice in records 1 and 2, its 'parent' would be returned. It corresponds to the table 1 record 1, so the name of the record with table1 id: 1 should be returned, which is etc. Example also as it has a count of 1 in the bottom column, however foo does not appear so it shouldnt.
Expected result:

```
name
foo
etc
```

Comment: Sample data is great, but you should also _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Edited, I didn't have a current query attempt as I wasn't sure what to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a subquery in the `where` clause:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where (select count(t3.id)
       from table2 t2 left join
            table3 t3
            on t3.table2_id = t2.id
       where t2.table1_id = t1.id
       group by t2.id
       order by count(*) asc -- to get the minimum
       limit 1
      ) >= ?  -- value you care about
```

I suspect that this might have the best performance with appropriate indexes:  `table2(table1_id, id)` and `table3(table2_id)`.

Comment: The performance is useless if the code is wrong and your code is wrong: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=f7e76b06c555747ca9db5f5e7ade4400

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood the question - if a check on table3.table2_id is greater than 0, the answer would be 'etc' ?
Code below

```
select t1.name
from 
(
 select 0 as id, 1 as table2_id 
 union select 1, 0
 union select 2 , 0
) t3

inner join 
(
select 0 as id ,  1 as table_id
union select 1, 0
union select 2, 2
) t2 on t2.table_id = t3.table2_id
inner join 
(
select 0 as id,  'foo' as name 
union select 1   , 'etc'
union select 2   , 'example'
) t1 on t1.id = t2.table_id
 where t3.table2_id > 0
```

Comment: Does not work for this case: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=c04e9410da0002933fff2e2702ad1088

Answer (score 0):

```
select table1.name 
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.table1_id
INNER JOIN table3 ON table2.id=table3.table2_id
GROUP BY table1.name 
HAVING count(*) >= 1
```

replace the last `1` with whatever `n` you desire

Here's the sql fiddle if you want to play around with it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/14217/4

Comment: Does not work for this case: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=7276aa866d1eb5d57936dd53afd0bf94

Comment: I agree that your query implements the logic differently. I will let the poster decide if it suits his needs. It all comes down on how you interpret `ALL corresponding records have  count of at least n`.  You interpreted the `ALL` as `each one of them`. I interpreted it as counting them as  a whole.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `INNER` join of `table1` to `table2` and then a `LEFT` join to `table3` and count the corresponding `id`s of `table3`.
Then by a 2nd level of aggregation return only the rows of `table1` where all the counters are at least `1`:

```
SELECT id, name
FROM (
  SELECT t1.id, t1.name, COUNT(t3.id) counter 
  FROM table1 t1
  INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.table1_id = t1.id
  LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.table2_id = t2.id
  GROUP BY t1.id, t1.name, t2.id
)
GROUP BY id, name
HAVING MIN(counter) >= 1 -- change to the number that you want
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=81ea0501d6de9485d5b974e93679382f).
Results:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | foo |
| 1 | etc |